# .Net website create directory to remote server access denied

Tags: .net, iis, access-denied, remote-server, create-directory

I have a web application that creates directories.
The application works fine when creating a directory on the web server, however, it does not work when it tries to create a directory on our remote fileserver.

The fileserver and the webserver are in the same domain.
I have created a local user in our domain, "DOMAIN\aspnet".  The local user is on both servers.

I am running my .Net app pool under the domain user. I have also tried using windows impersonate in the web.config to run under the domain user.

I have verified that the domain user has full control to the remote directory.  In an effort to debug this I have also given the "everyone" full control to the remote directory.

In an effort to debug this I have also added the domain user to the administrators group.

I have a simple .net test page on the web server to test this.
Through the test page I am able to read the directory on the file server and get a list of everything in it.

I am not able to upload files or to create directories on the file server.

Here's code that works:

```
var path = @"\\fileserver\images\";
 var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (var d in di.GetDirectories())
            {
                Response.Write(d.Name);
            }
```

Here's code that doesn't work:

```
 path = Path.Combine(path, "NewDirectory");
 Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Here's the error I'm getting:
Access to the path '\fileserver\images\NewDirectory' is denied.

I'm pretty stuck on this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a path issue.

\fileserver\images\ was mapped to h:\files\http\images

The service had permissions to the drive at H, but not the share.

Answer (score 0):

Check the trust level of the server/site. If you're running at less than Full Trust then you may need to modify your `FileIOPermission` setting:

```
<IPermission 
   class="FileIOPermission" 
   version="1" 
   Read="$AppDir$" 
   Write="$AppDir$" 
   Append="$AppDir$" 
   PathDiscovery="$AppDir$"/>
```

The `$AppDir$` macro value expands to the folder your website resides in. You can append additional paths by separating them with semi-colons.

The file you need to edit will be pointed at by the `<trust level=.../>` setting in the master `web.config` file in `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`, presuming that you're running .NET 2.0.